# OpenSSL in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, openssl

I'm trying to make a bash script in linux where some encrypted data is embedded and then retrieved and decrypted with openssl, like this:

```
cat | openssl des3 -d -a -salt -pass pass:asdf > output.txt <<EOF
U2FsdGVkX1/zN55FdyL5j1nbDVt5vK4V3WLQrnHPoycCJPwWO0ei3PCrrMqPaxUH.....blablablah data
EOF
```

The only problem with this, that would otherwise work, is that I have to hit enter when the script reaches this position. I have tried changing the way \n are placed, but no luck.

I can't afford to press manually enter for all the files that are going to be embedded like this one!!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things wrong here:

1. You shouldn't use both `cat | ...` and also a here document (`<<EOF`).  Use one or the other.
2. Your example isn't testable because the example text is not the DES3 encryption of any input.

This example works as expected:

```
cat ~/.profile | openssl des3 -e -a -salt -pass pass:asdf -out /tmp/output.txt
```

That is, it writes an encrypted version of `~/.profile`, base64 encoded, to file /tmp/output.txt.

Here's a working decryption example with a here document:

```
openssl des3 -d -a -salt -pass pass:asdf <<EOF                                              
U2FsdGVkX1/03DBd+MpEKId2hUY82cLWpYltYy2zSsg=
EOF
```

Try this in the safety and comfort of your own home...

Comment: Actually, the original poster wants to `decode`, not encode. But simply getting rid of the unnecessary `cat |` will fix the problem in both cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot Norman! I couldn't figure it out. Do you know also how could I do the same with tar?? I can apply the same method, I don't get tar to receive the right input: tar xf - <<EOF doesn't work, I have to make an ugly hack with tail -n+(the number of the current line) and pipe it with tar xf -.  :S  Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: tar archives tend to contain weird characters like nulls that you don't want in your shell scripts.  Instead, include the base64-encoding of the tar archive, and extract with `openssl base64 -d <<B64_EOF | tar -xf -` (note: I included an underscore in the here-doc delimiter to make sure it can't occur inside the here-doc).

Comment: @Alvaro: You might be better off avoiding shell here documents entirely.  If not, be sure there are no $ signs or ` signs in the encoding.  Gordon's idea is a good one; I would also quote <<'B64_EOF'.

Comment: @Norman: Quoting the delimiter (which prevents interpretation of $, \, and ' in the here-doc) shouldn't be necessary with base64 (which only uses upper- and lowercase letters, digits, +, /, =, and in some weird circumstances *) -- OTOH, it won't hurt and is safer with other encodings.

Comment: I want to keep entire tree structures with different encriptions in one single file :) I managed to do everything with your help guys! :) thank you very much!